# Create a dictionary/look up table in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to store opening times of shops in a file, every shop has 7 differents opening times, one for every day of the week and I have a like 2000 shops.

Instead of wasting space I figured out I could write only a indexkey and store only the opening times that are not equal to each other in a separate file. But to do so I need an hashtable/lookup table to check if they opening time I'm inserting it's or it's not already in the file.

This is the code so far:

```
orarioString = DateToSec(Opening) + DateToSec(Closing);
int value;
if(orarioDict.TryGetValue(orarioString, out value))
{
    sw.Write("{0,4}", value);
}
else
{
    orarioDict.Add(orarioString, index++);
    sw.Write("{0,4}", index);
}
```

`orarioDict is a Dictionary<String,int>` but I don't know it's the correct data structure because I need to insert and keep track of my "index" manually. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Would using a lightweight database be a option? Soring this much information in a file seems like a job for SQLite or similar.

Comment: I don't see why you would worry about wasted space if there is only 7 * 2000 DateTimes to store (112ko).

Comment: Unluckly I cannot do this because these data are stored in a database and I need to extract them and write to files which are the input of another program.

Comment: @EldritchConundrum because I need to feed this data to a legacy program (a 20 year old fortran monster) which is not in my control and I think it's not optimized for large data, so I prefer to do this in c#

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution here is `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`.  This is the logical mapping of store key to a list of times per store.  I think the worry about space here is unwarranted especially since `List<int>` can be sized to exactly the number of desired entries.

Comment: Since there are a known number of opening times - 7, one for each day, I think an Array would be a more logical choice than List.  Then you could even store them indexed by the DayOfWeek.

Comment: @MichaelBray true, i'm still a bit unsure if there are exactly 7 or max of 7.  But array could be a better choice here under certain consrtaints

Comment: @JaredPar the problem is this opening times are 7 for every shops but they can be like "9-15" or "8:30-23" "10-12". So with 2000 shops I'm expecting like 100-200 different opening time, the majority like "9-18" and than a some odd hours

Comment: @Federico then why not store the time as a string or custom struct?